# bitmap problem. There is no file with an icon in the given path

Tags: python, tkinter, bitmap

I have a Python application where I use tkinter to set an .ico icon on a window.  I make an .exe using pyinstaller, by default, for some reason, the application does not pick up the icon with the .ico extension, I just paste it in the dist folder and everything works, but the problem is that I make the installer of this program using InnoSetup and on my laptop it  works, but as soon as I install the application on another laptop and run it, I get the same error again that there is no such file in this path.  Is there any solution to this problem at all?  Maybe someone has come across something similar.

[image: screeb]

Comment: What tool did you use to create the executable?  You have to TELL that tool to include the `ico` file in the distribution.  Otherwise, how would it know you needed it?  This is why many people embed their small resources as base64 encoding in their source code.

Comment: @TimRoberts, What do you mean by "tool"

Comment: @TimRoberts I use a pyinstaller.

I write: pyinstaller --hidden-import="sklearn.utils._typedefs" --hidden-import="sklearn.neighbors._partition_nodes" --noconsole --onefile --icon=img/clustering.ico main.py

Comment: That makes it the icon for your executable.  It doesn't collect the import into the bundle.  You can use `--add-data` for that.

Comment: @TimRoberts How to write - - appdata and path or what?

Comment: @Ivan213 `--add-data` is used to add additional non-binary files or folders to the executable. check the docs: https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html#cmdoption-add-data